# Good font for a rest home logo?

Tags: fonts

I need to make a logo for an old age home, but I've had trouble selecting a font. It needs to be friendly, but not too cartoony. Does anyone have a good font idea?

This is the logo (it is WIP, and my first Logo :( )

[Logo concept http://i.imagebanana.com/img/5answqdr/senioren.jpg](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/5answqdr/senioren.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of types of font to look into:

---

### Rounded sans serifs

A popular type of font that meets these criteria is [**rounded sans serifs**](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1141). The rounding adds a note of soft, approachable friendliness - but the shape and therefore overall tone is still solid and professional. There's none of the obtrusive novelty of the W, K and X of the font in your example, or the silly childishness of cartoony fonts.

Serious, with a smile.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The most famous of the type is [Calibri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibri) - but it's worth thinking twice before using it in a logo because, as the default font in recent versions of Microsoft Office, it could look over-familiar and plain unless it's set very well.

Here's a list of the typography-obsessed users of [Typophile's favourite rounded sans-serifs](http://typophile.com/node/35956), and here's a list unscienficially [collect from Twitter](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1141). Or [search any font site for rounded sans](http://www.fontshop.com/search/?q=rounded%20sans).

Be aware that they're quite fashionable at the moment. So for now, they're great, but there's a risk that by 2022 they might look "so early 2010s". Probably a risk worth taking as they're generally pretty subtle.

---

### Humanist sans serifs

If you want something a little more mature-looking, look for [Humanist sans serifs](http://www.graphic-design.com/Type/bergsland/humanist.html) - sans serif fonts with generous open proportions and a tiny, subtle splash of handwriting-like curvy uneven charm. [Here's a list to browse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Humanist_sans-serif_typefaces), or use it as a [search term on any font site](http://www.fontshop.com/search/?q=humanist).

[image]

[image]

---

Never let a random stranger on the internet who knows almost nothing about your client tell you which typeface best suits their organisation's character and brand. But hopefully there's enough here to help you get started finding the right font.

Comment: Careful with Optima, though. It's been abused in the past few decades. That said, It's not out of line for this project. Good suggestion.

Comment: I actually think the last paragraph should go first. There is a whole lot of information missing to make a relevant decision.

Comment: Wow...thank you so much for this big post! (':